# how to get the text value from selected li and pass it to input in another li using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    function create_custom_dropdowns() {
   $('select').each(function (i, select) {
    if (!$(this).next().hasClass('dropdown')) {
     $(this).after('<div class="dropdown ' + ($(this).attr('class') || '') + '" tabindex="0"><span class="current"></span><div class="list"><ul></ul></div></div>');
     var dropdown = $(this).next();
     var options = $(select).find('option');
     var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
     dropdown.find('.current').html(selected.data('display-text') || selected.text());

     if ($(this).hasClass('area')) {
      dropdown.find('ul').append('<li class="option"><input id="displayValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Min"> <input id="idValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Max"> </li>')
     }
     options.each(function (j, o) {
      var display = $(o).data('display-text') || '';
      dropdown.find('ul').append('<li class="option ' + ($(o).is(':selected') ? 'selected' : '') + '" data-value="' + $(o).val() + '" data-display-text="' + display + '">' + $(o).text() + '</li>');
     });
    }
   });
  }
 
  $('.area').on('change', function () {
   document.getElementById('displayValue').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
   document.getElementById('idValue').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  })

  $(".box1").change(function () {
   var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
   $(".area-ft").val(selected);
   if (selected === "0") {
    $(".area-ft").show();
   } else {
    $(".area-ft").hide();
   }
  });

  // Open/close
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function (event) {
   $('.dropdown').not($(this)).removeClass('open');
   $(this).toggleClass('open');
   if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).find('.option').attr('tabindex', 0);
    $(this).find('.selected').focus();
   } else {
    $(this).find('.option').removeAttr('tabindex');
    $(this).focus();
   }
  });
  // Close when clicking outside
  $(document).on('click', function (event) {
   if ($(event.target).closest('.dropdown').length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
    $('.dropdown .option').removeAttr('tabindex');
   }
   event.stopPropagation();
  });
  // Option click
  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown .option', function (event) {
   $(this).closest('.list').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   var text = $(this).data('display-text') || $(this).text();
   $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.current').text(text);
   $(this).closest('.dropdown').prev('select').val($(this).data('value')).trigger('change');
  });

  // Keyboard events
  $(document).on('keydown', '.dropdown', function (event) {
   var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
   // Space or Enter
   if (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
     focused_option.trigger('click');
    } else {
     $(this).trigger('click');
    }
    return false;
    // Down
   } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
     $(this).trigger('click');
    } else {
     focused_option.next().focus();
    }
    return false;
    // Up
   } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
     $(this).trigger('click');
    } else {
     var focused_option = $($(this).find('.list .option:focus')[0] || $(this).find('.list .option.selected')[0]);
     focused_option.prev().focus();
    }
    return false;
    // Esc
   } else if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
     $(this).trigger('click');
    }
    return false;
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-drop listing-drops">
<form class="serc">
<select name="zone" class="zone ">
<option value="volvo">Bangalore East</option>
<option value="saab">East</option>
<option value="fiat">West</option>
<option value="audi">South</option>
</select>
<select name="zone" class="locality">
<option value="volvo">All Localities</option>
<option value="saab">East</option>
<option value="fiat">West</option>
<option value="audi">South</option>
</select>
<select name="zone" class="area box1">
<option value="volvo">Area</option>
<option value="saab">East</option>
<option value="fiat">West</option>
<option value="audi">South</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="search button button--aylen">Find Properties</button>
<button type="button" class="clear-filter">Clear Filters</button>
</form>
</div>
```

This below code is for dropdown. I need to pass the text value to input which is in li from the another selected li. Both input should have different selection. and both selected value need to pass to the main div span which have class current

```
<div class="dropdown area" tabindex="0">
    <span class="current">East</span>
    <div class="list">
       <ul>
         <li class="option">
           <input id="displayValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Min"> 
           <input id="idValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Max"> </li>
         <li class="option" data-value="volvo" data-display-text="">Area</li>
         <li class="option  selected" data-value="saab" data-display-text="">East</li>
         <li class="option " data-value="fiat" data-display-text="">West</li>
         <li class="option " data-value="audi" data-display-text="">South</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried using this

$('.area').on('change', function () {
        document.getElementById('displayValue').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById('idValue').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    })

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. Please explain your issue with more details.

Comment: please create a working code snippet of your code. thanks

Comment: i want to take the text value from li tags after the input boxes and want to pass those values to input box

Comment: use `select` and not `li` :https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: li is coming from js plugin i have used select only

Answer (score 0):

on change event will not work,because when you click on li tag that doesn't change any input
 check -> [definition](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)

try ->

```
$('.area li').on('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('displayValue').value = 
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('idValue').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an click event on your li elements and then you have to write the text from your clicked li element into your input fields.

```js
$(".option").on("click", function(){
   if($("#displayValue").val() === ""){  //If first input empty...
     $("#displayValue").val($(this).text()); //...write into first input
   }else{
     if($("#displayValue").val() !== $(this).text()){ //if value from first input not equal selected value
       $("#idValue").val($(this).text()); //...write into second input
     }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown area" tabindex="0">
  <span class="current">East</span>
  <div class="list">
    <ul>
      <li class="option">
        <input id="displayValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Min">
        <input id="idValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Max"> </li>
      <li class="option" data-value="volvo" data-display-text="">Area</li>
      <li class="option  selected" data-value="saab" data-display-text="">East</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="fiat" data-display-text="">West</li>
      <li class="option " data-value="audi" data-display-text="">South</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` event means using [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) DOM with `option`

```js
    $('.area').on('change', function () {
        $('#displayValue').val($("select option:selected").text());
        $('#idValue').val($("select option:selected").text());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="area">
  <option value="Area">Area</option>
  <option value="East">East</option>
  <option value="West">West</option>
  <option value="South">South</option>
</select>

<input id="displayValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Min"> 
<input id="idValue" class="area-ft" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Max"> </li>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: i want those input fields inside the dropdown like options not outside the dropdown select